# setup spring bean configuration for dbcp2 gives "PoolableConnectionFactory not linked to pool. Calling setPool()"

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-mvc

I need to convert dbcp2 java setup code into spring beans

The below code works as expected:

```
protected  void setupDriver(String connectURI, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        //
        // First, we'll create a ConnectionFactory that the
        // pool will use to create Connections.
        // We'll use the DriverManagerConnectionFactory,
        // using the connect string passed in the command line
        // arguments.
        //
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(connectURI, username, password);

        //
        // Next we'll create the PoolableConnectionFactory, which wraps
        // the "real" Connections created by the ConnectionFactory with
        // the classes that implement the pooling functionality.
        //
        poolableConnectionFactory = 
                new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
        logger.info("poolableConnectionFactory created");

        //
        // Now we'll need a ObjectPool that serves as the
        // actual pool of connections.
        //
        // We'll use a GenericObjectPool instance, although
        // any ObjectPool implementation will suffice.
        //        
        connectionPool =
                new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>(poolableConnectionFactory,getPoolConfig());
        logger.info("connectionPool created");

        // Set the factory's pool property to the owning pool
        poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
        logger.info("connectionPool is set to poolableConnectionFactory");

        //
        // Finally, we create the PoolingDriver itself...
        //
        Class.forName("org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDriver");
        driver = (PoolingDriver) DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:");
        logger.info("dbcp2 driver is created");

        //
        // ...and register our pool with it.
        //
        driver.registerPool(poolName,connectionPool);
        logger.info("driver is registered");

        //
        // Now, we create the PoolingDriver itself,
        // passing in the object pool we created.
        //
        dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection>(connectionPool);       
        logger.info("dataSource is created");

        //
        //Finally we create the JdbcTemplate for sql 
        //operations in DbDAO class
        //
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);        
        logger.info("jdbcTemplate is setup");

        logger.info("Finally dbcp2 driver setup is completed!");

    }   

    //Pool initial setup values
    private GenericObjectPoolConfig getPoolConfig(){

            logger.info("Let's create the pool config values");
            GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
            poolConfig.setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(config.getMaxtotal())); // set number of max connections i.e 25
            poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(Long.parseLong(config.getMaxwaitmillis())); //ie. wait for a minute = 60000
            poolConfig.setMaxIdle(Integer.parseInt(config.getMaxidle())); // set max number of idle connections
            /*poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
            poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);*/
            //poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
            //poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(10000L);
            //poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(5);
            //poolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(5000L);

            return poolConfig;
}
```

And this is the beans.xml

```
<!-- ============ Trauma Database Connection Pooling Beans Settings ================== -->  
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverManagerConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0"  value="${tir.jdbc.url}" />
        <constructor-arg index="1"  value="${tir.jdbc.username}" />
        <constructor-arg index="2"  value="${tir.jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Connection Factory -->
    <bean id="poolableConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" >  <null/> </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <!-- Pool Configs -->
    <bean id="poolConfig" class="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig">
        <property name="maxTotal" value="${pool.maxtotal}"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${pool.maxidle}"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="${pool.minidle}"/>
        <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="${pool.maxwaitmillis}"/>
    </bean>    
    <!-- Connection Pool -->
    <bean id="connectionPool" class="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="poolableConnectionFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="poolConfig"/>
    </bean>       

    <!-- Datasource gets connection pool -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionPool"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- JdbcTemplate bean gets the datasource -->
    <bean id="jdbcTemplateTIR" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />       
    </bean>
    <!-- Finally, we create our Database object bean -->
    <bean id="dbdao" class="edu.uams.dao.impl.DBDAO">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplateTIR" />
    </bean>
    <!-- ============= END OF Trauma Database Connection Pooling Settings =========== -->
```

In both situations I can use the jDBCTemplate objects, however it gives the following warning:
***"WARN     0[main] - org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.(PoolingDataSource.java:65) PoolableConnectionFactory not linked to pool. Calling setPool() to fix the configuration"***

The reason is obvious: In my java code, I setup

```
poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
```

How can I call setPool method from beans?

And how can I also setup this java code in my beans? The constructor of DriverManagerConnectionFactory does not get any constructor of DriverClassName?

```
            // Finally, we create the PoolingDriver itself...
            //
            Class.forName("org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDriver");
            driver = (PoolingDriver) DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:");
            logger.info("dbcp2 driver is created");

            //
            // ...and register our pool with it.
            //
            driver.registerPool(poolName,connectionPool);
```

Comment: Why so complex? Why aren't you simply configuring a `BasicDataSource` which does most of this implicitly.

Comment: I just posted an explanation down there.. I guess BasicDataSource doesn't give us the control to manage the pools

Comment: What is it that you want to manage that cannot be done with the `BasicDataSource` you can control the max, min, idle timeouts... For what I can see what you posted here can be done with a `BasicDataSource`.

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't it be easier if you just used `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`?  According to the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html) it provides a *"one stop shopping" solution* for basic connection pooling.

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.jdbcurl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a solution to exactly this problem given in the question with these specific versions of the libraries. I used the Spring configuration you gave and tweaked it a little bit, and I was able to get it working. Here is how I am using it...

```
<bean id="poolingDataSourceBean" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="genericObjectPoolBean" class="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean id="poolableConnectionFactoryBean" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory">
                    <constructor-arg index="0">
                        <bean id="dataSourceConnectionFactoryBean" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean id="dataSourceBean" class="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource">
                                    <property name="serverName" value="${database.server}"/>
                                    <property name="portNumber" value="${database.port}"/>
                                    <property name="databaseName" value="${database.name}"/>
                                    <property name="user" value="${database.user}"/>
                                    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg index="1"><null/></constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **PoolableConnectionFactory not linked to pool. Calling setPool() to fix the configuration"** warning because PoolingDataSource has pooling defined while PoolableConnectionFactory does not. With spring you run into circular dependency: PoolableConnectionFactory needs GenericObjectPool that needs PoolableConnectionFactory in constructor.

One way to get around it is to use MethodInvokingFactoryBean (or MethodInvokingBean in spring 4.0+):

```
<bean id="connectionPoolSetter" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" >
    <property name="targetObject" ref="poolableConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setPool"/>
    <property name="arguments" ref="connectionPool" />
</bean>
```

then add depends-on attribute to dataSource to make sure connectionPoolSetter is initialized:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource" depends-on="connectionPoolSetter">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionPool"/>
</bean>
```

Check Pooling Data Source example code:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java?view=markup

Answer (score -1):

By the way, I also have a DBPoolManager which I can manage the pool itself, even printing the stats.. even I haven't find any solution yet, I hope this code will be useful for you..

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;


public class DBPoolManager {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBPoolManager.class);  
    private static DBPoolManager dbPoolManager = null;
    private static final String POOLNAME = "dbpool";
    private DBPoolDriver poolDriver = null;
    private String url = null;
    private String username = null;
    private String password = null;
    private static DriverStats stats = null;


    protected DBPoolManager(){}

    public void init(String url, String username, String password ){
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        try{            
            this.poolDriver = new DBPoolDriver(POOLNAME);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }   

    public static DBPoolManager getInstance(){

        if(dbPoolManager == null){
            synchronized(DBPoolManager.class){
                if(dbPoolManager == null){
                    dbPoolManager = new DBPoolManager();
                    logger.info("Created a new singleton of DBPoolManager: "+dbPoolManager);                    
                }
            }
        }
        else{       
            logger.info("Created the same singleton of DBPoolManager: "+dbPoolManager);
        }

        return dbPoolManager;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
        return  poolDriver.getJdbcTemplate();
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception{

        return poolDriver.getConnection();
    }

    public void setupPool() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        try{
            poolDriver.setupDriver(url, username, password);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }   

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    } 

    public int getMaxTotal() {
        return Integer.parseInt(poolDriver.getConfig().getMaxtotal());
    }
    public void setMaxTotal(int maxTotal) {     
        poolDriver.getConfig().setMaxtotal(String.valueOf(maxTotal));
    }

    protected long getMaxWaitMillis() {
        return Long.parseLong(poolDriver.getConfig().getMaxwaitmillis());
    }

    public void setMaxWaitMillis(long maxWaitMillis) {      
        poolDriver.getConfig().setMaxwaitmillis(String.valueOf(maxWaitMillis));
    }
    public int getMaxIdle() {
        return Integer.parseInt(poolDriver.getConfig().getMaxidle());
    }

    public void setMaxIdle(int maxIdle) {       
        poolDriver.getConfig().setMaxidle(String.valueOf(maxIdle));
    }

    public int getNumActive() throws SQLException{
        return poolDriver.getConnectionPool().getNumActive();
    }
    public int getNumIdle() throws SQLException{
        return poolDriver.getConnectionPool().getNumIdle();
    }
    public void shutDownPool() throws SQLException{
        poolDriver.close();
    }

    public void printDriverStats() throws Exception {
         logger.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " NumActive: " + dbPoolManager.getNumActive());
         logger.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " NumIdle: " + dbPoolManager.getNumIdle());
    }
```